# await Promise.reject or throw error to bail out?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am refactoring my promise chaining codes to async/await style. One of the reasons to do that is I want a single catch block to handle to all error situations (as explained here [Understanding promise rejection in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739491/understanding-promise-rejection-in-node-js))

My question is when I hit a sync error, should I call `await Promise.reject` or `throw error` to bail out the process? 
I know either way will work but I prefer `throw error`. I already know I got an invalid result why should I await? Using throw to terminate the control flow immediately seems to be a better option.

I am not talking about the promise chain(the whole point of my question), so I don't think the thread [JavaScript Promises - reject vs. throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw]) answered my question.

I read the article [Error Handling in Node.js](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors) I don't think it gives an answer either. But it did say

> A given function should deliver operational errors either
>   synchronously (with throw) or asynchronously (with a callback or event
>   emitter), **but not both**.  ... In general, using throw and expecting
>   a caller to use try/catch is pretty rare...

My async function(s) may return Promise.reject. So I am concerned about introducing 2 ways to delivering errors as that article against.

```
try {
   let result = await aysncFunc().
   if (!isResultValid(result)) { //isResultValid() is sync function 
      await Promise.reject('invalid result')
      //or throw 'invalid result'
   }
   ... //further processing
}
catch (error) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `I know either way will work but I prefer throw error` - well, go forth and do that - but are you sure either way will work?

Comment: "but are you sure either way will work?" I am 99% sure. But that is also one of the reasons I asked my question.

Comment: Of course it is 100% works (as in your code block).  I prefer to throw error directly +1, anything you throw in the sync code could be caught.  It just more elegant and nature. `await Promise.reject()` is redundant, and potentially could cause confusions for some people.

Comment: But I think you may hit to a bad direction.  Don't use `async/await` just trying to be fashionable.  Use it when it is really needed; i.e. async operation, and also use `await Promise.all([...])` if you have two or more independent async operations.

Comment: Also, another reason for it is performance, but it just marginal in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's semantically correct to use `throw` in promise control flow, this is generally preferable way to bail out of promise chain.

Depending on coding style, `await Promise.reject(...)` may be used to differentiate between real errors and expected rejections. Rejected promise with string reason is valid but `throw 'invalid result'` is considered style problem that may be addressed with [linter rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-throw-literal), because it's conventional to use `Error` instances as exceptions.

The reason why it's important is because string exceptions can't be detected with `instanceof Error` and don't have `message` property, consistent error logging as `console.warn(error.message)` will result in obscure `undefined` entries.

```
// ok
class Success extends Error {}
try {
  throw new Success('just a friendly notification');
} catch (err) {
  if (!(err instanceof Success)) {
    console.warn(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
}

// more or less
const SUCCESS = 'just a friendly notification';
try {
  await Promise.reject(SUCCESS);
} catch (err) {
  if (err !== SUCCESS)) {
    console.warn(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
}

// not ok
try {
  throw 'exception';
} catch (err) {
  if (typeof err === 'string') {
    console.warn(err);
  } else {
    console.warn(err.message);
  }

  throw err;
}
```

Since `invalid result` is actually an error, it's reasonable to make it one:

```
  throw new TypeError('invalid result');
```

> I am not talking about the promise chain(the whole point of my question), so I don't think the thread JavaScript Promises - reject vs. throw answered my question.

`async` function is syntactic sugar for promise chain, so all points that are applicable to promises are applicable to `async` as well.

There may be cases when throwing an error is not the same as rejecting a promise, but they are specific to other promise implementations like AngularJS `$q` and don't affect ES6 promises. Synchronous error in `Promise` constructor results in exception, this also isn't applicable to `async`.

Comment: I added the words "I am not talking about the promise chain ..." just to emphasize that I knew that discussion (in case someone will say it is a duplicated question). Also, I am more concerned about the pros and cons of using one over the other

Comment: It's a matter of style, and `throw` is more conventional. I hope I covered pros and cons. It's *It's semantically correct to use throw in promise control flow* vs *Rejected promise with string reason is valid but throw 'invalid result' is considered style problem*.

Comment: BTW, the article Error Handling in Node.js did say "A given function should deliver operational errors either synchronously (with throw) or asynchronously (with a callback or event emitter), but not both. "

Comment: Since `async` introduces sync-like control flow, it's the first part of the sentence that is applicable.

Comment: Does really people `throw` a plain string...?! Come on, it's a really a bad practice.  And as I said, for the pros and cons, IMO, there is no pros at all for using `await Promise.reject()` if your know you have as `sync` operation.  It just like you have a function, and wrap with another function which just return the function.  PS.  `Promise.reject()` should also be passed with an `error` object, not a string, though you can do it.

Comment: @LeoLi They generally don't. But since `async` function is just syntactic sugar, and primitives are commonly used as rejection reasons, that's what we have. `await Promise.reject()` is a syntactic sugar for `.then(() => Promise.reject(...))` which is acceptable way to designate that a rejection isn't really an exception; basically a matter of style. Any way, I personally consider `throw new Success(...)` a cleaner way to achieve same goal.

Comment: @estus no, it actually not equivalent. Because you can't not just monkey patching the above code to the same place.  And I generally don't like the saying **async/await is a syntactic sugar for promise**, it actually is a generator sugar which return a `Promise`. (think about the `co` module, that's how `async(-> *)/await(-> yield)` implemented)

Comment: And I have to say a bad/redundant code is not a 'style' at all.  think about you have a function named `const hello = () => console.log('hello')` and you have another function as `const sayHello = () => hello()`.  That is how stupid `await Promise.reject('some_sync_operation')` was.  At the very bottom (in the implementation of `async/await` sugar generator), it still throw the error, which why `catch` can catch it.

Comment: Any async..await code has a `Promise` counterpart, that's why it's syntactic sugar. `co` and similar attempts were precursors for async. *At the very bottom (in the implementation of async/await sugar generator), it still throw the error, which why catch can catch it* - it could be caught from the outside with `.catch()`. Because it's rejected promise. Not an exception. It's a good thing that you're opinionated towards good practices, but this is primarily a matter of style and there can be more than one opinion on that.

Comment: Redundant code is acceptable if it serves the purpose, i.e self-documenting code. A lot of proper code could be written in more obscure but concise way.