# ES6 JS Promises - how to avoid conditional nesting

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to write a piece of code using promises, avoiding nesting them but I am stuck in testing the returned results to handle the promises flow ..
Is this pattern workable ??

**// set of promise tasks returning values**

```
    function doTask1() => {
        return apiPromise1()
         .then((result1) => {
             return result1;
         })
    }
    function doTask2(result1, paramOne) => {
        return apiPromise2(result1, paramOne)
         .then((result2) => {
             return result2;
         })
    }
    function doTask3(result1) => {
        return apiPromise3()
         .then((result3) => {
             return result3;
         })
    }
    function doTask4(result1, paramOne) => {
        return apiPromise4()
         .then((result4) => {
             return result4;
         })
    }
```

**// main promise to handle the flow of promises according to promises returned results**

```
    function getCurrentProcess(paramOne) {
        const promises = [];

   // how to get the returned result1 to be used by other promises ?
        promises.push(doTask1); 
        if (result1 === 'OK') {
            promises.push(doTask2(result1, paramOne));

            if (result2 === 'OK') {
                promises.push(doTask3(result1));

                if (result3 === 'OK') {
                    promises.push(doTask4(result1, paramOne));
                }
            }
        }

        return Promisz.all(promises)
        .then(() => {
            return 'well done'
        });

    }
```

**// initial calling function**

```
    exports.newJob = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      const paramOne = { ... }
      getCurrentProcess(paramOne).then((res) => {
        return { status: 200, infos: res };
      }, error => {
        return {status: error.status, infos: error.message};
      }).then(response => {
        return res.send(response);
      }).catch(console.error);
    });
```

Comment: It would be easier if you would reject those promises if their response is not `'OK'`. That way you won't need to do any of those conditions.

Comment: thanks for your feedback... in some cses I need to test the response ..  i.e when the response is a list, I need to search into this list and based on the search result to execute the next promise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a wrapper function which takes an array of `doTaskN` as deferred functions:

```
const conditional = (...fns) => {
  if(fns.length === 0) return Promise.resolve();
  const [next] = fns;
  return next()
    .then(() => conditional(...fns.slice(1)));
};
```

The idea would be to pass in the reference to the `doTask` functions so that the `conditional` function executes them. This can be used like:

```
conditional(doTask1, doTask2, doTask3, doTask4)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("all done");
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("failed");
    });
```

Here's a full example of how to use it:

```js
const conditional = (...fns) => {
  if(fns.length === 0) return Promise.resolve();
  const [next] = fns;
  return next()
   .then(result => {
      console.log("task:", result);
      if(result === "OK") {
        return conditional(...fns.slice(1))
      }
    });
};

const task1 = (param1, param2) => Promise.resolve("OK");

const task2 = (param1) => Promise.resolve("OK");

const task3 = () => Promise.resolve("failed");

const task4 = () => Promise.resolve("OK");

conditional(() => task1("one", 2), () => task2(1), task3, task4)
 .then(() => {
      console.log("all done");
    })
 .catch(() => {
      console.log("failed");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write promises in more procedural way you need use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)  (ES6). If you need backward compatibility with ES5 you need to use babel or typescript which translate await/async to ES5.

```
async function getCurrentProcess(paramOne) {
    const result1 = await doTask1(); 
    if (result1 === 'OK') {
        const result2 = await doTask2(result1, paramOne);

        if (result2 === 'OK') {
            const result3 = await doTask3(result1);

            if (result3 === 'OK') {
                await doTask4(result1, paramOne);
            }
        }
    }

    return 'well done'

}
```

Without async/await you need to use promise chain:

```
doTask1().then((result1)=>{
   if (result1 === 'OK') {
      ...
   }
   ...
})
```

However it will not produce readable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your promise return result is used by other promises, you shouldn't use `Promise.all()` method because it doesn't run methods in the order you want, it just waits for all of the promise methods to complete and returns all results.

Maybe something like [promise-array-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-array-runner) would help?

Maybe you could check if `result === 'OK'` inside your task method? Or create a `Factory` which takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .then((result1) => {
     return result1;
 })
```

is a no-op and should be omitted, but I suppose that real code doesn't have this problem.

This is a use case for `async` function because they can seamlessly handle this sort of control flow, as another answer suggests. But since `async` is syntactic sugar for raw promises, it can be written in ES6. Since tasks depend on results of each other, they cannot be processed with `Promise.all`.

This is same case as [this one that uses `async`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575613/await-promise-reject-or-throw-error-to-bail-out).

You can bail out from promise chain by throwing an exception and avoid nested conditions with:

```
// should be additionally handled if the code is transpiled to ES5
class NoResultError extends Error {}

function getCurrentProcess(paramOne) {
    doTask1()
    .then(result1 => {
      if (result1 !== 'OK') throw new NoResultError(1);
      return result1;
    })
    .then(result1 => ({ result1, result2: doTask2(result1, paramOne) }))
    .then(({ result1, result2 }) => {
      if (result2 !== 'OK') throw new NoResultError(2);
      return result1;
    })
    // etc
    .then(() => {
        return 'well done';
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err instanceof NoResultError) return 'no result';
      throw err;
    })
}
```

Since `result1` is used in multiple `then` callbacks, it could be saved to a variable instead of being passed through promise chain.

Promise chain could become simpler if `NoResultError`s were thrown in task functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all feedbacks !!

All answers are rights... however I voted for CodingIntrigue wtapprer function solution in my case...

1 - As i am using Firebase functions , it's still ES5 , I cannot use sync/await. Using babel or typescript only for Firebase functions will result in much more setup work...

2 - I tested various use cases and this pattern is quite easy to understand with JS level...   I am sur that it can be improved later..

so finally I got this running ...

```
    let auth = null;
    let myList = null;

    const conditional = (...fns) => {
      if(fns.length === 0) return Promise.resolve();
      const [next] = fns;
      return next()
        .then(result => {
          if(result) {
            return conditional(...fns.slice(1));
          }
          return result;
        });
    };

    const task1 = (param1) => Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
        console.log('TASK1 executed with params: ', param1)
        auth = "authObject"
          return true;
        });

    const task2 = (param1, param2) => Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
        console.log('TASK2 executed with params: ', param1, param2)
          return true;
        });

    const task3 = (param1, param2) => Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
        console.log('TASK3 executed with params: ', param1, param2)
        myList = "myListObject"
        console.log('search for param2 in myList...')
        console.log('param2 is NOT in myList task4 will not be executed')
          return false;
        });

    const task4 = (param1) => Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
        console.log('TASK4 executed with params: ', param1)
          return true;
        });

    // FIREBASE HTTP FUNCTIONS ==================
    exports.newContactMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      conditional(() => task1("senderObject"), () => task2(auth, "senderObject"), () => task3(auth, "senderObject"), () => task4("senderObject"))
        .then((res) => {
        return { status: 200, infos: res };
      }, error => {
        return {status: error.status, infos: error.message};
      }).then(response => {
        return res.send(response);
      }).catch(console.error);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I see you want to use wrapper for your promise methods. I recently created https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-array-runner which is doing exactly that. Good luck!